# Webclient isn't dowloading everything from URL c#

Tags: c#, json, webclient, steam-web-api

I am trying to get every item name from the [steam community market](https://steamcommunity.com/market/) (I market where you buy and sell virtual items, which you can use in games).
Steam has an [API link](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=500) for this, it says `"total_count":15227`, which represents the number of Items.
**But when I try to download it, I get only 100 items**. Why is that so?
This is how I download it:

```
public static Task LoadAllItemsAsync()
{
     using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
     {
          var responseData = w.DownloadString("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=500");
           //StatTrak™ FAMAS | Sergeant (Battle-Scarred)
           dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);
           string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\SteamData\SteamItems.json"), jsonData);

           return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the response you can see the "pageSize" parameter that has the value 100.

Apparently 100 is the maximum page size the steam api returns.

```
{
   "success":true,
   "start":0,
   "pagesize":100,
   "total_count":15227,
   ......
}
```

So if you want to fetch all items you will need to do a loop. You can use the START and TOTAL_COUNT parameters to calculate the offset etc.

The below URL would skip the first 100 items and return the next 100.

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=100
```